# C++ SafeArrayLock/Unlock creates undefined reference

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, safearray

Whenever trying to use SafeArrayLock/Unlock I keep getting the message "undefined reference to 'SafeArrayLock@4'.

I'm using Code::Block and just copy/pasting the default microsoft example for safearrays:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/207931

If i remove the safearraylock/unlock function lines then my dll compiles just fine.  Put them back in and it tosses the undefined reference error.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221492(v=vs.85).aspx  scroll down to requirements add the library to your project

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the MSDN; i read it several times over before I realized I was including the wrong library - ole32 instead of oleaut32. Ooops!